# Angular-cli Auth0 login config

Tags: angular, jwt, angular-cli, auth0, angular2-jwt

I want to add angular2-jwt module to my angular project, but i don't know in which file i need to add node modules mapping  (I'm using  1.0.0-beta.28.3 angular-cli version),indeed I want do to add auth0 Single Sign On & Token Based Authentication And it gives me warning and nothing is shown on the browser

> ```
> ./src/app/Auth.service.ts
> There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
> This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
> Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
> * C:\Users\Wassim\angular workspace\gestionDocuments\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!C:\Users\Wassim\angular workspace\gestionDocuments\src\app\Auth.service.ts
>    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>    C:\Users\Wassim\angular workspace\gestionDocuments\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!C:\Users\Wassim\angular workspace\gestionDocuments\src\app\app.component.ts
> * C:\Users\Wassim\angular workspace\gestionDocuments\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!C:\Users\Wassim\angular workspace\gestionDocuments\src\app\auth.service.ts
>    Used by 3 module(s), i. e.
>    C:\Users\Wassim\angular workspace\gestionDocuments\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!C:\Users\Wassim\angular workspace\gestionDocuments\src\app\app.module.ts
> ```

and the browser give me this exception

```
EXCEPTION: No provider for Auth!
```

this is auth.service.ts

```
    // app/auth.service.ts

import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

// Avoid name not found warnings
declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock('y1LTKr8nqe45mF7MRVLiIU7r3GBApRfn', 'wess.auth0.com', {});

  constructor() {
    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult:any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    });
  }

  public login() {
    // Call the show method to display the widget.
    this.lock.show();
  }

  public authenticated() {
    // Check if there's an unexpired JWT
    // This searches for an item in localStorage with key == 'id_token'
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

  public logout() {
    // Remove token from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
  }
}
```

and this is app.module.ts

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, Http, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {routing} from "./app.routing";

import { provideAuth, AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import {Auth} from './auth.service';

export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp( new AuthConfig({}), http, options);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,


  ],
  providers: [
{
    provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
      deps: [ Http, RequestOptions ]
},
Auth
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of project structure?

Comment: I added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix the following error:

```
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
```

It means that you have to rename the files auth.service.ts and Auth.service.ts.
After that you can start debugging the challenges you face with auth and angular-jwt.

Answer (score 0):

**Note :** How to create service and naming it properly.

If you name your service file "myservice.service.ts", then your exported class should be: "Myservice".

From [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)

> The naming convention for service files is the service name in lowercase followed by .service. For a multi-word service name, use lower dash-case. For example, the filename for SpecialSuperHeroService is special-super-hero.service.ts

My suggestion is using angular-cli to create services. You don;t have to worry about case of the naming.

```
ng generate service auth
```

also can do

```
ng g service auth
```

This command will create new service called auth.service .